# extracting data through regexps is returning nil

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to extract a pair of string from a parsed PDF and I have this extract:

```
Number:731    /         13/06/2016                 1823750212                                   10/06/2016\n\n\n\n Articolo
```

http://rubular.com/r/GRI6j4Byz3

My goal is to get out the `731` and `1823750212` values.

I tried something like `text[/Number:(.*)Articolo/]` for the first steps but it's returning `nil` while on rubular it somewhat matches.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the format of the string is fixed (dates and the long number,) this will do the trick:

```
text.scan /\ANumber:(\d+).*?(\d{5,})/
#⇒ [[ "731", "1823750212" ]]
```

Comment: I met another string: `Number:\n        752    /         14/06/2016                1976400833                                   13/06/2016\n\n\n\n Articolo`, I tried going with a: `Number:.*?(\d{1,}).*?(\d{5,})` but it does not work in code, it does in rubular apparently

Comment: Make sure you have [multiline mode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html) enabled (`/.../m` modifier after the regexp.) This would do: `text.scan /\ANumber:\s*(\d+).*?(\d{5,})/m`.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that we do not know the length of either string (representations of non-negative integers) to be extracted, only that the first follows `"Number:"`, which is at the beginning of the string, and the second is preceded and followed by at least one space.

```
r = /
    (?<=\A\Number:) # match beginning of string followed by 'Number:' in a
                    # positive lookbehind
    \d+             # match one or more digits
    |               # or
    (?<=\s)         # match a whitespace char in a positive lookbehind
    \d+             # match one or more digits
    (?=\s)          # match a whitespace char in a positive lookbehind
    /x              # free-spacing regex definition mode

str = "Number:731  /  13/06/2016  1823750212  10/06/2016\n\n\n\n Articolo"
str.scan(r)
  #=> ["731", "1823750212"]
```

If there could be intervening spaces between the colon and `"731"`, you could do modify the regex as follows.

```
r = /
    \A      # match beginning of string followed by 'Number:' in a
            # positive lookbehind
    Number: # match string 'Number:'
    \s*     # match zero or more spaces
    \K      # forget everything matched so far
    \d+     # match one or more digits
    |       # or
    (?<=\s) # match a whitespace char in a positive lookbehind
    \d+     # match one or more digits
    (?=\s)  # match a whitespace char in a positive lookbehind
    /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode

str = "Number:  731  /  13/06/2016  1823750212  10/06/2016\n\n\n\n Articolo"
str.scan(r)
  #=> ["731", "1823750212"]
```

Here `\K` must be used because Ruby does not support variable-length positive lookbehinds.